# How many people were employed in the UK making Sinclair computers?

Tags: history, sinclair

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinclair_Research) Sinclair Research had only 140 employees at its peak in the 1980s. I was surprised the number was so small for a company that sold something like five million computers, then I remembered they contracted out at least some of their manufacturing to Timex in Scotland (which also led to the deal whereby versions of some of their computers were sold in America under the 'Timex Sinclair' label).

So counting both Sinclair and Timex employees, but only the UK, not America, or places like Eastern Europe where unauthorized clones of the Spectrum were made, how many people were employed making Sinclair computers?

Comment: I don't think we can count the Eastern Bloc, there were so many random little workshops knocking out very short production runs. Impossible to say.

Comment: @OmarL Indeed, which is why I propose counting only the UK, where it should be much more feasible to obtain figures.

Comment: Sinclair gave most production jobs to external manufacturing companies. And only some of them located in UK. For them Sinclair jobs were only part of the business, so it's rather hard (if not fruitless) to calculate a number of employees. Also, Timex had much of it's development _and_ production in Spain.

Comment: @Raffzahn Okay, so it's a lot more complicated than I realized. Fair enough; that in itself is interesting.

Comment: Timex had much of its production and development in Portugal, not Spain, but that was only after Timex shut down its computer division.  Timex of Portugal continued on its own making computers derived from the TS2068, 48K Spectrum and completing various peripherals.  Timex Dundee was the plant used to make 48K spectrums early on.